# Image fuzzy after transition CSS 3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When I scroll on my [web site](http://be-crowd.com), I see my logo image fuzzy few seconds. 
CSS is :

```
#logo img {
    -webkit-transition: height .4s ease, opacity .3s ease;
    -o-transition: height .4s ease, opacity .3s ease;
    transition: height .4s ease, opacity .3s ease;
}
```

An idea why the logo is fuzzy fews seconds after a **transition** (css) ?

Comment: Use `transform:scale(0.5)` instead of changing the height, the transition will be much smoother :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can sometimes happen when resizing a PNG - but it really doesnt help that your current logo is 1600px wide!

```
http://be-crowd.com/images/Be-Crowd-30.png
```

I would suggest doing it double size of its standard max size (for retina) so maybe around 600px wide.

Or use an SVG as these scale better!